# Get named tuple variables from win32com.client.CDispatch object

Tags: python, pywin32, win32com

I'm trying to get some information about a system for a given Windows machine using pywin32's win32com module.

For example, this script finds how many CPU sockets a system may have, and tell me how many physical and logical cores are on each socket.

```py
import win32com.client
winmgmts_root = win32com.client.GetObject("winmgmts:root\\cimv2")
cpus = winmgmts_root.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Processor")
    for cpu in cpus:
        print(cpu.NumberOfCores)
        print(cpu.NumberOfLogicalProcessors)
```

The thing is, these variables don't exist when I try to look at the `cpu` object in the loop:

```py
for cpu in cpus:
    for name in dir(cpu):
        value = getattr(cpu, name)
        print("name: {}".format(name))
        print("value: {}".format(value))
```

This yields a ton of methods that start with `_` so they should not be used, and no indication of where the named tuple variables `NumberOfCores` and `NumberOfLogicalProcessors` coem from, even though I can confirm they exist.

How can I get a list of these named tuple variables?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fool - the `cpu` variables from the `cpus` object have named tuples as defined in the `Win32_Processor` class.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-processor